# why both transform and map methods in scala?

Tags: api, scala, dictionary, lazy-evaluation

I'm having trouble understanding the difference between / reason for, for example, immutable.Map.transform and immutable.Map.map.  It looks like transform won't change the key, but that just seems like a trivial variation of the map method.  Am I missing something?

I was expecting to find a method that applied a function to the (key,value) of the map when/if that element was accessed (rather than having to iterate through the map eagerly with the map function).  Does such a method exist?

Comment: To me, ``transform`` is just a clean way of doing ``myMap map { case (k, v) => (k, f(k, v)) }``. About your second question (which seems not closely related to the first one?), are you just looking for something like ``updated``?

Comment: @kane: yeah, I guess, it just seemed odd to have so many similar variations, especially when I couldn't find the other more useful function I was looking for.
The function I want does exist though, 0___'s answer of "andThen" is actually the one I want.  Sorry for combining two unrelated questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only need the interface of `PartialFunction`, you can exploit the fact that `Map` inherits from `PartialFunction`:

```
val m = Map(1 -> "foo", 2 -> "bar")
val n = m.andThen(_.reverse)

n(1)  // --> oof
```

Comment: hmm....  Maybe I didn't read this clearly enough, now I actually don't think this is what I was looking for....  since this only transforms the value, without access to the key.

Answer (score 4):

You can do exactly that with `mapValues`. Here is the explanation from the docs:

> def mapValues[C](f: (B) ⇒ C): Map[A, C]
>
> Transforms this map by applying a function to every retrieved value.
>
> **f** - the function used to transform values of this map.
>
> **returns** - a map view which maps every key of this map to f(this(key)). The resulting map wraps the original map without copying any elements.

**edit**:

Although extending classes of the collection API is not often a good idea, it could work like this:

```
class LazilyModifiedMap[A,B,C](underlying: Map[A,B])(f: (A,B) => C) extends Map[A,C] {
  def get(key: A) = underlying.get(key).map( x => f(key, x))

  def iterator = underlying.iterator.map { case (k,v) => (k, f(k,v)) }

  def -(key: A) = iterator.toMap - key

  def +[C1 >: C](kv: (A,C1)) = iterator.toMap + kv
}
```

Comment: Yep, but transform takes two-argument function from both key and value, whereas mapValues takes only one argument -- from value. Let's say you want to append key to value and have a new Map(key, key+value) as the result -- you can't archive this with mapValues. (just wondering why transform exists, if mapValues and map cover 99.9% percents of use cases)

Comment: yeah, as nom nom said, not very useful without the key.  So many methods in scala collections and yet...

Comment: @cmbaxter: nah, you can map from a Map to a List or something too:
scala> Map(1->"one",2->"two").map{ case (k,v) => "hi" }
res9: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[java.lang.String] = List(hi, hi)

Comment: Sorry, that was not clear from your post: `I was expecting to find a method that applied a function to the value of the map when/if that element was accessed`

Comment: @drexin: ah, yeah, I'll clarify that then.